# Background Overflow and CSS Ribbons

Tags: css, background-image

I was experimenting some fancy CSS effects before apply to an ongoing application and I came across [Ribbons](http://www.cssportal.com/css-ribbon-generator/).

By itself, it works perfectly but I wouldn't use a fixed element as suggested by the generator so I added an image to the main box

However, the images of the application in which I would be adding this feature are not of the same size yet, so I decided to change the old `<img>`for CSS background images and then make use of `background-size` property.

But sometimes the background image is overflowing the dimensions of box. It would be just a matter of add an `overflow: hidden` in **#preview** and everything would be solved, but if I do that the "curves" of the Ribbon disappear.

How could I change that? Here's the current test code, although for some reason the background is not loading, not in here nor in JSFiddle.

```css
#preview {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  display: block;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  height: 260px;
  width: 365px;
}

  .front {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-image: url( 'https://photos.smugmug.com/Dog-Shows/BTB-September2013-Sunday/BTB-UKC-Alaskan-Klee-Kai/i-xFmLHS8/0/S/889_MG_6212a-889-S.jpg' );
  }

.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px; top: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75px; height: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}
.ribbon span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: #79A70A;
  background: linear-gradient(#F70505 0%, #8F0808 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px; left: -21px;
}
.ribbon span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
.ribbon span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview">

  <div class="ribbon">
    <span>POPULAR</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="front"></div>
  
</div>
```

The image goes to `.front` because I also intend to use [David Walsh's Card Fliping technique](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip), which is already working in parallel and I believe is not relevant to the case.

Even setting `background-size` to `contain`made the image overflow, but this value is not desirable as it won't cover like the currentlt defined value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.front` is just a text container. you need to apply background image to `#preview`

```css
#preview {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  display: block;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  height: 260px;
  width: 365px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-image: url( 'https://photos.smugmug.com/Dog-Shows/BTB-September2013-Sunday/BTB-UKC-Alaskan-Klee-Kai/i-xFmLHS8/0/S/889_MG_6212a-889-S.jpg' );
}

  .front {
    color: white;
  }

.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  left: -5px; top: -5px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75px; height: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}
.ribbon span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: #79A70A;
  background: linear-gradient(#F70505 0%, #8F0808 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px; left: -21px;
}
.ribbon span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
.ribbon span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview">

  <div class="ribbon">
    <span>POPULAR</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="front">FRONT DIV Lorem ipsum la-la-la</div>
  
</div>
```

Or you need to define width and height for `.front`:

```css
#preview {
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;

  border: 3px solid #000;
  display: block;
  /*overflow: hidden;*/
  perspective: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  height: 260px;
  width: 365px;
}

  .front {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-image: url( 'https://photos.smugmug.com/Dog-Shows/BTB-September2013-Sunday/BTB-UKC-Alaskan-Klee-Kai/i-xFmLHS8/0/S/889_MG_6212a-889-S.jpg' );
   height: 260px;
  width: 365px;
 }

.ribbon {
  position: absolute;
  left: -8px; top: -8px;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 75px; height: 75px;
  text-align: right;
}
.ribbon span {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 20px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  width: 100px;
  display: block;
  background: #79A70A;
  background: linear-gradient(#F70505 0%, #8F0808 100%);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px -5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 19px; left: -21px;
}
.ribbon span::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-right: 3px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
.ribbon span::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute; right: 0px; top: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  border-left: 3px solid transparent;
  border-right: 3px solid #8F0808;
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-top: 3px solid #8F0808;
}
```

```html
<div id="preview">

  <div class="ribbon">
    <span>POPULAR</span>
  </div>
  
  <div class="front"></div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: While I was waiting for an answer I tried that, as it makes much more sense, however when I did that, the Card Flipping that was working perfectly (95% the same of David Walsh's, just renamed classes) kept the background applied while flipping, [take a look](https://jsfiddle.net/6ctghvdj/)

Comment: Probably I didn't catch the essence of the question

Comment: No, you did, but the common sense of where to apply the background conflicted with a different effect. I'll end this to not become an off-topic. Thank you :)